# Adding program to mingw32's "path"

Tags: windows, ruby, environment-variables, mingw32

I am running a rails app locally through NetBeans which seems to be running ruby through mingw32. I'm trying to do a system call to lame, which works fine using just irb, but this particular setup can't find it!

What can I do to tell mingw/this instance of rails where lame is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution to what I asked, but by using

```
system "c:/lame/lame.exe input.wav output.mp3"
```

I was able to get what I wanted